# How to detect indirect self inclusion in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have the table `assets` with the columns `id` and `name`, and the table `asset_inclusions` with the columns `including_asset_id` and `included_asset_id`. There is a constraint preventing `including_asset_id = included_asset_id`.

Is is possible to write a query to detect assets which include themselves indirectly?

For example if asset1 includes asset2 and asset2 includes asset1, the query would return asset1.

Or if asset1 includes assets2, assets2 includes asset3, asset3 includes asset1, the query would return asset1.

Assuming a recursive approach is needed, it's fine if the query looks for indirect self inclusion only through a max number of layers (e.g., 10) if that can ensure the query won't run forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to detect loops but IMHO, it is more efficient to prevent them from occurring in the first place, with a trigger.

### Detecting loops: principle

We build a path of ids in an `array` which, thanks to the `array_position` function, serves at both stopping the recursion when a loop is detected and selecting the corresponding ids.

```
WITH RECURSIVE LookRecursively(including_asset_id, included_asset_id, IDPath) AS (
    SELECT *, ARRAY[included_asset_id]
    FROM asset_inclusions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LookRecursively.including_asset_id, asset_inclusions.included_asset_id, IDPath || asset_inclusions.included_asset_id 
    FROM LookRecursively
    JOIN asset_inclusions ON LookRecursively.included_asset_id= asset_inclusions.including_asset_id
    WHERE array_position (LookRecursively.IDPath, asset_inclusions.included_asset_id) IS NULL 
)
SELECT included_asset_id, IDPath
FROM LookRecursively
WHERE array_position(IDPath, including_asset_id) IS NOT NULL
```

Edit: As suggested in comments, PostgreSQL14 and later have a `CYCLE` option on CTEs to perform that same task. PostgreSQL builds a column to flag if a loop was detected and a flag column itself; no need to write an array like I did above. Also note that the recursive part of the CTE only uses columns from table `asset`, no more `LookRecursively.ID` in there (otherwise the path would be incorrect).
The resulting query is very slightly different:

```
WITH RECURSIVE LookRecursively(including_asset_id, included_asset_id) AS (
SELECT *
    FROM asset_inclusions
    UNION ALL
    SELECT asset_inclusions.*
    FROM LookRecursively
    JOIN asset_inclusions ON LookRecursively.included_asset_id= asset_inclusions.including_asset_id
) CYCLE including_asset_id SET is_cycle USING path
SELECT *
FROM LookRecursively
WHERE is_cycle
```

The downside is that loops have several starting point and may be intertwined.
Example, with 2 loops `1->2->3->4->1` and `1->3->5->1`:

- `1->2->3->4->1`, `2->3->4->1->2`, `3->4->1->2->3`, `4->1->2->3->4` are all the same loop.
- `1->3->5->1`, `3->5->1->3`, `5->1->3->5` are also the same loop.
- `1->2->3->5->1`, `4->1->2->3->5->1->3->4` and a few more can be built from the above loops.

That could potentially cause a lot of data to be returned, more so than strictly needed for loop detection.

### Preventing loops: trigger

A trigger can get rid of some of the above issues by working with a single starting point (for each row being inserted/updated) instead of a `SELECT * FROM`.
More precisely, the trigger function raises an exception if it detects a loop from a given starting point. The associated trigger executes it for every row being inserted/updated.

Working sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asset_inclusions (
    including_asset_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    included_asset_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asset_inclusions_LoopDetection() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(
             WITH RECURSIVE LookRecursively(including_asset_id, included_asset_id, IDPath) AS (
                SELECT NEW.including_asset_id, NEW.included_asset_id, Array[NEW.included_asset_id]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT LookRecursively.including_asset_id, asset_inclusions.included_asset_id, IDPath || asset_inclusions.included_asset_id 
                FROM LookRecursively
                JOIN asset_inclusions ON LookRecursively.included_asset_id = asset_inclusions.including_asset_id
                WHERE array_position (LookRecursively.IDPath, asset_inclusions.included_asset_id) IS NULL 
            )
            SELECT FROM LookRecursively
            WHERE array_position(IDPath, including_asset_id) IS NOT NULL 
        ) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Loop detected';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER asset_inclusions_NoLoopTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON asset_inclusions
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION asset_inclusions_LoopDetection();
```

Note that the `CYCLE` option does not seem to work for the trigger though, so it would seem the above syntax is the only solution.

Comment: Starting with Postgres 14, you can also use the `cycle` option of the CTE to detect cycles.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is a good point and I edited the answer accordingly. I cannot seem to be able to make it work in the trigger function though (tested on Postgres 14.2); any idea why it is so?

Comment: @Atmo ty very much for your answer! I'll go with the trigger approach, it's more efficient indeed. I'm not sure I understand the answer's code though; my `assets` table has no `included_asset_id` column. I have 2 tables: `assets` with the `id` and `name` columns, and `asset_inclusions` with the `including_asset_id` and `included_asset_id` columns.

Comment: Oops, I must have been confused by having 2 tables... the loops are entirely contained into asset_inclusions, that is why. Does the version I just edited now help?